# How to detect ips using nmap?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, bash-scripting, nmap, local

I am currently working on demonstrating Man in middle Attack foe which I am using my phone as a Victim and my PC running ubuntu 14.04LTS as attacker. I am using nmap to ping my phone to check if its online...

```
nmap -e wlan0 -sn 172.16.95.198
```

But don't know how even when phones on same network I get a result ..

```
Note: Host seems down. If it is really up, but blocking our ping probes, try -Pn
Nmap done: 1 IP address (0 hosts up) scanned in 1.54 seconds
```

So I tried with -Pn as well but output remains the same (host seems down) which is not the case. The phone is up and running... Please help I am new to networking what am I possibly doing wrong???

Answer (score 0):

First - Did you try a ping on the IP - 172.16.95.198 from you Ubuntu ?

I usually do a port scan for different devices by nmap -v -A IPADDRESS

which also shows the host is UP / DOWN.